# mysql Link to server lost, unable to reconnect

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following error:

```
Link to server lost, unable to reconnect
```

I have a mysql daemon coded, and I use mysql_pconnect to connect to mysql but after a while, I get the following error and the daemon stops functioning properly:

```
Link to server lost, unable to reconnect
```

What I do is the following:

```
while(true)
{
  $connect = mysql_pconnect(...);
  $db = mysql_select_db(...);
}
```

What can I do to prevent this? I need mysql connection to stay steady for the whole duration of the daemon - which may be forever.

Comment: You are reconnection as fast as you can in an infinity loop? If I where mysql, I would block you too ;)

Comment: Why exactly are you using mysql_pconnect within a while(true) loop? That will only give you the guarantee that you'll hit your max connection limit on the server.

Comment: As @PiTheNumber mentions, this also resulted, for me, from an infinite redirect, where page 1 was redirecting to page 2 which was redirecting to page 1, and they both were opening mysql connection sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices.

But just as a precursor, you should try and move away from relying on mysql_* and start using the PDO instead.

Anyway...
When you open a mysql connection, it will stay "available" until the wait timeout has expired. What you are doing is constantly creating a new connection, (also without closing the other connection). This means you will either hit the server mysql limit, or your unix box socket limit **very quickly**.

### Wait Timeout

You should first check with your server to see what this timeout is set to. 
You might want to consider increasing it in your my.cnf if it is terribly low. The default period is `28800` seconds (if I recall correctly).

You can check by issuing this query:

```
SHOW variables like "%wait_timeout%"
```

You can then change the value in your my.cnf to increase it or you can also set it using

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=288000
```

### SELECT 1

Okay, now, with a reasonable set timeout set, the "typical" way that you can make sure that you don't get the `mysql has gone away` message, is to just do a `SELECT 1`. This will do another query and make sure that the connection is held open.

And, the benefit of using the PDO is that you can then catch PDOExceptions which might be thrown when a SELECT 1 fails.

This means, that you can then try and connect again, if an exception is thrown, and then check again. If you can't connect after that then you should probably kill your daemon. 
Here is some code.... you would clearly have to make your PDO object using a valid connection string.

```
    // $pdo holds the connection and a PDO object.  
    try {
            $pdo->execute("SELECT 1");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Mysql has gone away. 
            $pdo = null
            $pdo = new PDO( $connectionString );
            echo "Mysql has gone away - But we attempted to reconnect\n";
            try {
                 $pdo->execute("SELECT 1");
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                 echo "Mysql has failed twice - Kill Daemon\n";
                 throw($e);
            }
      }
```

This is the solution that I would probably take.

You can easily substitute the `SELECT 1` with your own query that you actually want to use. This is just an example.

Comment: The short version is that mysql_* functions have never really matured to a *solid* code base. When using PDO, it is extremely difficult to create a query that could potentially fubar your entire application. Whereas, with mysql_* you need to know what you are doing from day 1. mysql_* is perfectly suitable for any applicaiton, it will get the job done, but most people don't understand how to properly sanitize, whereas when you use PDO, you kind of have to jump through those hoops as you go.

Comment: do you know what a good number of seconds to set for the wait timeout for a daemon that I want to last forever? without depleting server resources...